# Accessing descriptor instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

When one defines a descriptor value retrieval etc. is overriden, making the instance of the descriptor effectively unaccessible.

I.e. one can't write `instance_with_descriptor_attr.descriptor_attr.some_method_on_descriptor()`... won't work. My question is basically how one can still access the descriptor's instance anway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go up to the class itself:

```
type(instance_with_descriptor_attr).descriptor_attr
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     @property
...     def bar(self): return 'bar'
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
'bar'
>>> type(foo).bar
<property object at 0x109f24310>
```

Comment: That works for a `property`, but a data descriptor in general might not return itself when accessed via the class, so you'd need to search the dict of the class and its bases.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by eryksun, Martijn's solution works for properties but not all descriptors:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.val = val

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val

class Test(object):
    x = Desc(5)

>>> o = Test()
>>> print o.x
5
>>> print Test.x
5
```

The reason it works for property descriptors can be seen in the example property descriptor implementation in the docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties

the key is the `__get__` function:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    if obj is None:
        return self
    if self.fget is None:
        raise AttributeError, "unreadable attribute"
    return self.fget(obj)
```

If obj is None it returns self, which is the instance of the descriptor itself.  obj is the instance of the class accessing the descriptor.  When you access the attribute from a class instance, obj is that instance, when you access it from a class object, then obj is None.

Changing the previous descriptor to:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.val = val

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val

class Test(object):
    x = Desc(5)
```

yields (class must be re-defined if you're using a python shell)

```
o = Test()
>>> print o.x
5
>>> print Test.x
<__main__.Desc object at 0x23205d0>
```

Comment: This doesn-t answer the question. The descriptor is still accesible. See next answer comment or my own answer 

Answer (score 0):

if the `__get__` method of the descriptor dont have a "`return self`" statement then the descriptor can only be accessed by the `__dict__` attribute of the class:

```
class descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return 1

class A:
    d = descriptor()

a = A()
a.d # --> 1
A.d # --> 1
A.__dict__['d'] # --> <__main__.descriptor object at ...>
```